# Unable to execute query due to variables not decoding

Tags: sql, mysql, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

i am using grafana 10.0.0v

i am getting sql query from a mysql table which i am storing in a variable and when i use the variable it should trigger the query present in the variable,it is working fine if it doesnt have any variables in the returned query,but if it has variables then it is not decoding the value instead it is passing the variable name itself to the query

query saved in mysql table is

```
SELECT timeStamp AS time,CAST($best_cell_mro_kpi AS DECIMAL(20,5))*100 as MRO_KPI FROM lab_mro_aggr_data_new WHERE $__timeFilter(timeStamp) and clusterID=''$best_cell_clusterID'' and $best_cell_ecgiID is not null and $best_cell_mro_kpi is not null ORDER BY timestamp
```

i am storing this in a variable called **best_cell_cdf** and this variable i am using in the query panel as ${best_cell_cdf:raw}

```
SELECT timeStamp AS time,CAST($best_cell_mro_kpi AS DECIMAL(20,5))*100 as MRO_KPI FROM lab_mro_aggr_data_new WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1695637351) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1696242151) and clusterID='$best_cell_clusterID' and $best_cell_ecgiID is not null and $best_cell_mro_kpi is not null ORDER BY timestamp
```

when i run the query $best_cell_mro_kpi,$best_cell_ecgiID and $best_cell_mro_kpi should be replaced with actual values of variables which are already present in the dashboard

i want to get the actual variable values in place to execute query,how do we do it

Comment: Grafana substitutes variables only once. AFAIK, it's not possible to pass variable inside content of another variable for substitution later. But you could manually substitute variables in query when retrieving queries in the first place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your query for retrieval queries, and query from second screenshot. And also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have replaced the image with query directly,i am getting the query from sql table which i need to execute if u observe the $__timeFilter(timestamp) is being replaced with actual values but other variables are not getting substituted